# How do I find the amount of levels in an Octree if I have N nodes?

Tags: algebra, octree

If the octree level is 0, then I have 8 nodes. Now, if the octree level is 1, then I have 72 nodes. But if I have (for example) 500 nodes, how do I calculate what the level would be?

Comment: Where are you stuck with the algebra?  For instance, *why* do you have 8 and 72 nodes for the first two examples?  How does that generalize for 2, 3, and 4 levels?

Comment: @Prune Out of every node, the octree creates 8 nodes. A base octree has 8 nodes, so if I go 1 level deeper, the Octree creates 8 nodes out of those each 8 nodes, so 8*8 = 64 + the 8 from the base Octree = 72. And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the max number of nodes at level `n` you would calculate:

```
8**1 + 8**2 + 8**3 ... 8**n
```

So at level 2, that's `8 + 64`

This can be generalized as:

```
((8 ** (h + 1)) - 1)/7 - 1
```

In javascript you might write:

```js
function maxNodes(h){
  return ((8 ** (h + 1)) - 1)/7 - 1
}

for (let i = 1; i < 4; i++){
  console.log(maxNodes(i))
}
```

To find the inverse you will need to use Log base 8 and some algebra and you'll arrive at a formula:

```
floor (log(base-8)(7 * n + 1))
```

In some languages like python you can calculate `math.floor(math.log(7*n + 1, 8))`, but javascript doesn't have logs to arbitrary bases so you need to depend on the identity:

```
Log(base-b)(n) == Log(n)/Log(b)
```

and calculate something like:

```js
function height(n){
    return Math.floor(Math.log(7 * n + 1)/Math.log(8))
}

console.log(height(8))
console.log(height(72))  // last on level 2
console.log(height(73))  // first on level 3
console.log(height(584)) // last on level 3
console.log(height(585)) // first on level 4
```